# Why passed tuple argument from dictionary has trailing comma?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Recently I noticed that when I pass to the function argument which is tuple value from dictionary it has trailing comma at the end.
Bellow is the simple code example of my issue.

```
def myfun(*args):
   print(f'args={args}')
   x, y = args
   print(f'x={x}, y={y}')


myfun(1, 2) # passing arguments this way works fine
arg_dict = {0: (1, 2), 1: (2, 3)}
print(f'arg_dict[0]={arg_dict[0]}') # when I print dictionary value it seems quite OK.
myfun(arg_dict[0]) # passed dictionary value has trailing comma.
```

Here is the output:

```
args=(1, 2)
x=1, y=2
arg_dict[0]=(1, 2)
args=((1, 2),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\name\Documents\pname\test.py", line 28, in <module>
    myfun(arg_dict[0])
  File "c:\Users\name\Documents\pname\test.py", line 21, in myfun
    x, y = args
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I am wondering why python interpreter decides to pack tuple from dictionary like this?
*I am using python3.6.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass tuple as a first argument.
You need to unpack values:

```
myfun(*arg_dict[0])
```